# Where can I find a picture of the inflorescence of Epipremnum aureum (golden pothos)?

Tags: botany, flowers, photography

[*Epipremnum aureum* (golden pothos)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epipremnum_aureum) is a very popular house plant - attractive and almost impossible to kill.

Also, it is a flowering plant with flowers produced in a spathe up to 23 cm (9 in) long, according to Wikipedia.

I have been trying to find further documentation of these flowers, in particular a picture, without success. Can anyone help?

(Google image search produces some stock photos that claim to show *E. aureum* flowers but I am skeptical about these.)

Answer (score 1):

Figure 4d on page 6 of (Hung, 2016) shows a flower the authors managed to induce in E. aureum (This is one of the papers that mgkrebbs cited in his answer).
[image: Figure 4]
[Hung, 2016 - Chiu-Yueh Hung, Jie Qiu, et al., "Gibberellin deficiency is responsible for shy-flowering nature of Epipremnum aureum", Scientific Reports 27 June 2016, DOI: 10.1038/srep28598](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep28598) [Creative Commons Attribution 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/)

Answer (score 0):

You may find it quite hard to find an image of the flower of *Epipremnum aureum* as it is almost always described as "shy flowering".  Here "shy" seems to be an understatement, as the first recorded flowering was reported in 1962, and the latest report of flowering I found mentioned was from 1964 (Boyce, 2004).  Chiu-Yueh Hung *et al* say "Since 1962 there is no report of E. aureum flowering both in wild as well as in cultivation" (Hung, 2016).

Even though the name *Epipremnum aureum* was assigned in 1964, one still encounters it under several other names, including binomial names using the genus names of *Pothos, Scindapsus,* and *Rhaphidophora*.  Perhaps most problematically, one finds some use of *Epipremnum pinnatum* for it, as for some time it was considered a cultivar of that species based on the form of the flower. Consult Boyce for a good overview.

Boyce, 2004 - P. Boyce, "A review of Epipremnum (Araceae) in cultivation", *Aroideana* **27**:205 (2004) [[PDF]](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Peter_Boyce2/publication/308503215_A_Review_of_Epipremnum_Araceae_in_Cultivation/links/57e4fb1008ae25aa020b6646.pdf).

Hung, 2016 - Chiu-Yueh Hung, Jie Qiu, et al., "Gibberellin deficiency is responsible for shy-flowering nature of Epipremnum aureum", *Scientific Reports* 27 June 2016, DOI: 10.1038/srep28598, [[PDF]](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep28598.pdf).