# Has Epipremnum aureum lost its ability to reproduce sexually?

Tags: reproduction

In this recent question the shy flowering nature of Epipremnum aureum (Golden Pothos) was discussed:

[Where can I find a picture of the inflorescence of Epipremnum aureum (golden pothos)?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/74970/where-can-i-find-a-picture-of-the-inflorescence-of-epipremnum-aureum-golden-pot)

To summarize: (1) The two first and only observations of the plant flowering date back to the 60s and (2) genetic analysis yields a potential explanation for why the plant is so rarely flowering

Question: Is this sufficient evidence to conclude that E. aureum has lost its ability to reproduce sexually?

(Triggering thought: It is very unlikely that two specimens flower simultaneously, at a distance from each other that allows pollination, that pollination actually takes place and that the seeds germinate and successfully grow into new plants)